# Change size of Alert Dialog buttons

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-8

I have a problem with changing the size of the Alert buttons.

```
  Alert alert = new Alert(alertType);
  alert.setTitle(titulo);
  alert.setHeaderText(encabezado);
  alert.setContentText(mensaje);

  ButtonType button1 = new ButtonType(mensajeBoton1);
  ButtonType button2 = new ButtonType(mensajeBoton2);

  alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(button1, button2);

  Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();

  if (result.get() == button1) {
      return Dialog.Actions.OK;
  }
```

The problem is because the buttonType is small, and it is for use on a touch screen.

Answer (score 1):

You may access them by `dialogPane.lookupButton()` and apply custom style to them:

```
for ( ButtonType bt : alert.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes() )
{
    Button button = ( Button ) alert.getDialogPane().lookupButton( bt );
    button.setPadding( new Insets( 20 ) );

    // or define css style and apply it
    button.getStyleClass().add( "big-button" );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Uluk, if this increase size. but I can define it any size with style(mystyle)?

Comment: @MarcoR yes, follow the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) and then study [Skinning JavaFX Applications with CSS](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm) to see an example.